# What could be the alternative use of readObject method in java?

Tags: java, chat, inputstream, server

I am trying to build a simple instant messanger program. Right now I am coding for the serevr class what will run in the server side. The method I am working on at the moment is `whileChatting`.
This method should show the string message on the chat window until the user hits *END*.
Now, in order to read the input object in window I am using this line of code:

```
  message=(String)input.readObject();
```

which is showing an error that "method not found". Why is so? If there is no such method exist in java library then what can be used alternatively? I am going to paste the code for `whileChatting` method: [PLZ ask me if you need to see the code for the whole class]

```
      private void whileChatting(){
   String message="You are now connected";
   sendMessage(message);
   ableToType(true);
   do{
       try{
           message=(String)input.readObject();
           showMessage("\n"+message);

       }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException){
           showMessage("\n the input cean't be read");
       }

   }while(!message.equals("CLIENT-END"));

  }
```

Comment: What is input? Is it an ObjectInputStream? If not, then it makes sense that you're not finding the  method. Key information is missing from your question.

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels, I am not quite familiar with ObjectInputStream, and Yeah, may be it is! What I can tell about input is it's any string object i.e. character message what the user (or client) will input and the server side will read that. Do you need to see the complete code for the class?

Comment: Ryan -- you're still not telling us -- what the heck is `input`?? You can only use the methods available to the variable, and can't make up methods that don't exist for that variable. That's where you must start.

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels, the input is InputStream. I have assigned it like this: private InputStream input;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state:

> the input is InputStream. I have assigned it like this: private InputStream input;

Then you can check the API to see what methods InputStream has available to it, and you'll see that `readObject()` does not exist. Note that this is something you should be in the habit of doing in general as the Java API will give you much of what you need to know to allow you to use the classes available in core Java. Again, `readObject()` is not a method of InputStream but rather is a method of ObjectInputStream. Now one possible solution is to wrap your InputStream into an ObjectInputStream, and in doing so, this would allow you to use the `readObject()` method, but I'm going to suggest that you not do this, that you don't even bother with `readObject()` or any similar method. Instead why not create a Scanner object with your InputStream and get your Strings directly from the Scanner object via its `nextLine()` method.